# Controlling Docker Container from another machine

Tags: docker

I am creating a demo server hosting website. I use React for frontend and Express for backend. The server is a jar file. So what I want to do is when I call my backend api, I can remotely execute a command on the server. Or just display the console log of the server to the frontend.

My friend told me to make a docker image of the server and run it inside a container. I have done that.

My question is how will I be able to control the docker container remotely if my website is hosted on another server? Is there any API for Docker Daemon?

PS: I am very new to the Docker technology.

Comment: Docker does have an API (that's how the docker client talks to the docker daemon), and there are various ways of accessing it remotely. You may want to do a little research first; you'll find a variety of examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think that expess had to call jar, but .jar is not a service, is it ?
If it's just a jar you call with `java -jar yourjar.jar` you have to bundle Express and you jar in the same docker image and they will be on the same server.

In other way, there is a docker client (docker-cli), you can configure it to connect a remote host and call a docker command (`docker run yourimage java -jar yourjar.jar`) that is send to the server that host docker.

It need to exchange certificat and it's work over http.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/
https://gist.github.com/kekru/4e6d49b4290a4eebc7b597c07eaf61f2